# UICollectionView Dynamic Sized Cells in only one direction

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

Is there a way to dynamically size `UICollectionViewCell`s in only one direction, like height, while making the width follow the layout's itemSize dimension? Or is it all or nothing?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a cell for sizing purposes from NIB for example:

```
_sizingCell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([MyCell class]) owner:self options:nil] firstObject];
```

Let's assume that MyCell has a titleLabel for exmpl. Then you can let the autolayout calculate the size for you in collectionView:layout: sizeForItemAtIndexPath:

```
NSString *title = self.items[indexPath.item];
self.sizingCell.titleLabel.text = item.title;

CGSize size = [self.sizingCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];

return CGSizeMake(size.width, 33);
```

This operation can take a time, so I suggest to cache the calculated value. Let's create property `NSCache *cellWidthCache`

```
NSString *title = self.items[indexPath.item];
self.sizingCell.titleLabel.text = item.title;

NSNumber *cachedWidth = [self.cellWidthCache objectForKey:indexPath];

if (!cachedWidth) {
    cachedWidth = @([self.sizingCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].width);
    [self.cellWidthCache setObject:cachedWidth forKey:indexPath];
}

return CGSizeMake(cachedWidth.floatValue, 33);
```

Answer (score 1):

From iOS 8 on their is an api provided by Apple called Self-Sizing Cells, which is great and very easy to use (it does have some issues, but thoes are rather small compared to the benefits).

To use it you have to do two things:

1. Set up auto layout in your cell so that a height and width can be obtained from the constraints.
2. Simply set the estimatedItemSize property of the collection views layout object to a non-zero value:

   ```
   UICollectionViewFlowLayout *collectionViewLayout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout;
   collectionViewLayout.estimatedItemSize = //your estimated item size
   ```

That's it for self-sizing cells (for more info watch the WWDC 2014 video "What's New in Table and Collection Views")! If you want more fine grained control you will probably need to subclass UICollectionViewLayout...

Comment: I know about the self-sizing functionality and estimatedSize, my question is whether I can set an estimated size for the height but set a static size for the width. Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: Yes that is possible. I am doing the same thing just with a flexible width in my app. You just need to set up your constraints to a static width and have the constraints for the height be flexible e.g. Through specifying ">=" or "<=" as an attribute to the constraint (which you can do in interfacebuilder or in code)